# How to display the correct label.text depending on a randomised array index

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Beginner Here,

I'm coding a project that randomly matches up DOTA 2 heroes.

I'm currently pulling the hero image into the ImageViews from the fighters array using Int.random.

However, I'm now trying to implement a corresponding label underneath the image to display the name of the hero currently in the ImageView.

I'm initially trying to do this for fighterOne at fighters["1"] which would be Dragon Knight.

I've tried various 'if' statements, none of which seem to work. I've also scoured forums and documentation, but can't find the solution anywhere.

```
@IBOutlet weak var fighterOne: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var matchButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fighterOneName: UILabel!
let fighters = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",]


var randomIndex1: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateFighterName()
    updateFighters()
}


///// FUNCTIONS /////

func updateFighterName() {     
    if fighterOne.image == UIImage(named: "1") {
        fighterOneName.text = "Dragon Knight"
    } else {
        fighterOneName.text = "Wrong"
    }
}

func updateFighters() {
    randomIndex1 = Int.random(in: 0...11)
    fighterOne.image = UIImage(named: fighters[randomIndex1])
}
```

I can't make sense of the result I'm getting from this. When I run the app, the "Dragon Knight" is occasionally displayed, however, it's not under the correct hero image, it's very erratic as to when it's displayed, and there appears to be no logical display sequence from what I can tell.

Any help would be appreciated and let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `updateFighters()` before calling `updateFighterName()` inside your `viewDidLoad()` because you depend on what it does.

Your `viewDidLoad()` should look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateFighters()
    updateFighterName()
}
```

And you need to replace:

```
if fighterOne.image == UIImage(named: "1") {

}
```

With:

```
if fighterOne.image.isEqual(UIImage(named: "1")) {

}
```